# Fill color before or after recursive call (Flood Fill algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, segmentation-fault

I was implementing a basic version of the flood fill algorithm when I ran into this doubt.

When should you color the present cell (i.e. do `image[sr][sc] = newColor`) before the recursive calls or after the recursive calls? Why is there a difference between the two approaches? When the current cell is colored before the recursive calls works but if I change the order then it gives segmentation error.

Here's the code:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> floodFill(vector<vector<int>>& image, int sr, int sc, int newColor) {
    if(image.size()<=0 || image[sr][sc] == newColor) return image;
    int rows = image.size(),cols=image[sr].size();
    int temp = image[sr][sc];
    image[sr][sc] = newColor;
    //check up
    if((sr-1)>=0 && image[sr-1][sc] == temp){
        image = floodFill(image,sr-1,sc,newColor);
    }
    //check left
    if((sc-1)>=0 && image[sr][sc-1] == temp){
        image = floodFill(image,sr,sc-1,newColor);
    }
    //check right
    if((sc+1)<cols && image[sr][sc+1] == temp){
        image = floodFill(image,sr,sc+1,newColor);
    }
    //check down
    if((sr+1)<rows && image[sr+1][sc] == temp){
        image = floodFill(image,sr+1,sc,newColor);
    }
    //if i put the image[sr][sc] = newColor; here it give seg error
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Obviously you should colour it before, because colouring it after doesn't work, as you can plainly see. What's the question again?

Comment: Why doesn't the coloring after work ? just before returning to the calling function i can color and return right?(I am still new maybe i'm not seeing something obvious?)

Comment: It is best if you yourself figure out why colouring after doesn't work. Fire up a debugger and run it step by step on a 1x2 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to modify `image` in-place by reference, so there's no need to return it -- in fact, it's a bad idea to do so. Writing the cell to the new color after the recursive call won't work because the child call's base case-related tests of `image[sr+N][sc] == temp` and `image[sr][sc] == newColor` will be wrong -- the parent call plans to color the cell but since it has't gotten around to it, it's revisited, giving an infinite loop as it spawns more child calls.

Here's my suggestion in a runnable example you can adapt to your use case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void floodFill(
    std::vector <std::vector<int> > &image,
    int r,
    int c,
    int newColor,
    int oldColor
) {
    if (
        r < 0 ||
        c < 0 ||
        r >= (int)image.size() ||
        c >= (int)image[r].size() ||
        image[r][c] == newColor ||
        image[r][c] != oldColor
    ) {
        return;
    }

    image[r][c] = newColor;
    floodFill(image, r - 1, c, newColor, oldColor);
    floodFill(image, r, c - 1, newColor, oldColor);
    floodFill(image, r, c + 1, newColor, oldColor);
    floodFill(image, r + 1, c, newColor, oldColor);
}

void printMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &img) {
    for (auto row : img) {
        for (int cell : row) {
            std::cout << cell << " ";
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > img{
        {0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1,},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,},
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0,},
    };
    printMatrix(img);
    std::cout << "\n";
    floodFill(img, 2, 2, 1, img[2][2]);
    printMatrix(img);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 2 2 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 1 0

1 2 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 1 1
```

As you can see, you can remove a lot of repetition by making one base case check at the start of the recursive call. This adds an extra call relative to checking conditions in branches, but that's probably a premature optimization.

Comment: yea thanks a lot I got what i failed to see before, Thank you